# Linked image's SourceFullName differs from actual link

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a weird case in a word automation program I'm developing using the Office Interop and C# 3.5

One task of the program is to copy any linked images in the word document to a different location and rewrite the Linked Source of those images to the new location.

Now, in one document, when I check the linked files (using Word 2010), it points an image to a location similar to `images\image_file.jpg` - So, the image is in a subfolder of the folder where the document is. That's totally correct.

[image: Linked image editscreen]

But, when my program runs into that image, the `LinkFormat.SourceFullName` of that same image gives me a path on our local network, e.g. `\\net-storage\customer\001 - customername\data\images\documents\image_file.jpg`, without any correlation whatsoever to the **actual** image link I'm expecting.

What's going wrong here? How do I get the **correct** image source in my program?

Edit to *sw_lasse*: I'm sure this is a relative path, because (in other documents) after deleting the image in the relative path and updating the fields in word, the image is not found. So it's definitely a relative path.

Also, the two paths (network and relative) have no correlation to each other. The images on the network use a completely different folder hierarchy, so that's why there's a `document` subfolder, while it doesn't exist in the relative path.

Comment: Great question - I have been looking into this, and I need you to make some clarifications. You say that "when I check the linked files, it points an image to a location similar to images\image_file.jpg" - first of all, do you use the "Links" dialog to see this? If not, how do you check that? Secondly, are you sure Word reports this as a relative path? And finally, you mention two paths: `images\image_file.jpg` and `\\net-storage\...\images\documents\image_file.jpg` - is it on purpose that the first path does not include the `documents` folder inside the images folder?

Comment: I edited my question. I attached a screenshot where I check the image links. Unfortunately I can only provide that in german, but I think from the positioning you should be able to deduct if it's the same function you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your writing VSTO C# code and this is VBA, but I believe this explains the odd behaviour your seeing.

You cannot use:

```
myPicPath = Options.DefaultFilePath(wdPicturesPath)
```

**... because if the user has inserted a picture from a different folder, the Default File Path returns that folder rather than the actual setting from the dialog box.** Instead, you can use:

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogToolsOptionsFileLocations)
    .Path = "PICTURE-PATH"
    .Update
    myPicPath = .Setting

    If Not Right$(myPicPath, 1) = "\" Then
        myPicPath = myPicPath + "\"
    End If

    MsgBox myPicPath 
End With
```

Similarly, you cannot use:

```
myDocPath = Options.DefaultFilePath (wdDocumentsPath)
```

to get the default document path, because this returns the current FileOpen path, not the default documents path!!

Instead, use:

```
Dim myDocPath As String
myDocPath = Dialogs(wdDialogToolsOptionsFileLocations).Setting

'Add a "\" at the end of the path, unless the setting is already followed by a "\" -
'which it will be if the setting is set to a root folder 
If Not Right$(myDocPath, 1) = "\" Then
    myDocPath = myDocPath + "\"
End If

MsgBox myDocPath
```

These days I'm pretty good at converting VBA to C#, if you provide some code that doesn't work I'll convert this VBA to suit.

[Ref: How to retrieve Word's default Documents path or Pictures path setting](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/GetDocPath.htm)